# LAX Exception while running the installer on Linux (RHEL)

Tags: installanywhere

I created an installer for Linux using InstallAnywhere 2014 running on WIN 2008. I bundled JVM. When I tried to run the setup.bin on Linux it is throwing the below error.

```
[Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallBundle.shouldRegister(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraapl.bg(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraapl.bf(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraapl.ap(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraapl.ad(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.IAStatusLog.setInstallWasStarted(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Installer.install(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.consoleInstallMain(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
This Application has Unexpectedly Quit: Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)
```

Please let me know how to debug this issue. There is no other information even if I enable debugging.

I tried various posts. I observed that locales folder must consist custom_en file. I checked it and found it present.

Answer (score 1):

I came across that same NPE. Double check the Install Set via GUI:Choose Install Sets or Panel:Choose Install Sets. I checkbox "Show the 'Choose Product Features' without the 'Choose Install Sets'".
Doing so would make $CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET$ = Custom. In my case, my installer didn't like a particular install set, so when i made it a custom install set it worked for me as a workaround.